# Return an int[] after storing in a LinkedList

Tags: java

When I try and return my int[] it says it's an object and I cannot return it to int[].

```
public class CostMatrix {

LinkedList matrix = new LinkedList<int[]>();

CostMatrix() {
}

void addToMatrix(int[] toAdd) {
    matrix.add(toAdd);
}

int[] returnCost(int pos){

    return matrix.get(pos)
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a type parameter on the declaration.

`LinkedList matrix` -> `LinkedList<int[]> matrix`

To understand why you get this error, search for "raw types" in http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html

Basically, your code creates a correctly parameterized list but assigns it to a property with a *raw* type.

Then when you get from it, the compiler only knows that the property is a `LinkedList` and assumes that its content can be any type of `Object`.